# Ubuntu apache failed to start permission denied

Tags: apache, ubuntu

Im new in ubuntu

I got an error when I start the apache2

What I did first was uninstalling the apache2

`sudo apt-get purge apache2`

then I removed the `/usr/sbin/apache2` with `sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/apache2`

then install again the apache2

`sudo apt-get install apache2`

After that I tried to start the apache2 but it was failed to start

this is the error

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `sudo`?

Comment: @Dyno yes `sudo service apache2 restart`